# Html email formatting issue

Tags: html

I have a 3 column html email table see code below, everything aligns on the same row ok apart from one issue their a gap at the top of the last table column. The gap gets considerably worst going from outlook 2007 - 2013 the gap basically gets bigger.

My question is how do I eliminate this gap, to see what the problem more closely check it out here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdkel and hover over the third column.

Here is visual

http://take.ms/9qIva Outlook 2007

http://take.ms/a9FET Outlook 2013

CSS Resets

```
table {border-spacing:0;}
table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
table td, table tr { border-collapse: collapse; }


<tr>
                 <td align="center" valign="top" class="fix-box">

                     <!-- start LAYOUT-5 container width 600px -->
                     <table width="600" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="container">
                         <tbody><tr>
                             <td valign="top" width="100%">

                                 <!-- start LAYOUT-5 container width 560px -->
                                 <table width="560" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="full-width">

                                        <!-- start image and content -->
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td valign="top" width="100">
                                                <!-- start content left -->
                                                <table width="160" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="col-3" bgcolor="#ede8e7">

                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td width="100%" valign="top" align="left" class="image-160px">

                                                            <img src="http://passiondev.co.uk/email-newsletter/coats/imageplaceholder.jpg" width="160" alt="image5_280x210" style="max-width:100%;
 display:block !important; " border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0">

                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                 <!--start space height -->
                                                 <tr>
                                                     <td height="20"></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                                 <!--end space height -->

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                    <td style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; font-family:
 Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#621a4b; font-weight:bold; text-align:left;
 padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                                                                        Embroidery
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>

                                                             <!--start space height -->
                                                             <tr>
                                                                 <td height="15"></td>
                                                             </tr>
                                                             <!--end space height -->

                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px; font-family:
 Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#808080; font-weight:300;
 text-align:justify; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; ">

                                                                        Phoomph makes creating decorations and costumes fast and
 easy. Download our free e-book of 13 projects Halloween projects.

                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>

                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top" width="auto">
                                                                        <!-- start button -->
                                                                        <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="auto" align="center" valign="middle" height="40" style="border-radius:5px; font-size:14px; font-family: Arial,Tahoma,
 Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left;  color:#5f294f; font-weight: 300;
 padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; ">

                                                                                        <a href="http://www.makeitcoats.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f; font-weight: bold;">
                                                                                            <span style="color: #5f294f; font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;">
                                                                                                Read more
                                                                                            </span>
                                                                                        </a>

                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>

                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="auto" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-radius:5px; font-size:14px; font-family: Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; text-align:left;  color:#5f294f; font-weight: 300; padding-left:
 15px; padding-right: 15px; ">

                                                                                            <a href="http://www.makeitcoats.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f; font-weight: normal;">
                                                                                            <span style="color: #5f294f; font-weight: 300;
 text-decoration: none;">
                                                                                                Related link 1
                                                                                                </span>
                                                                                            </a>

                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>

                                                                                    <!--start space height -->
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td height="5"></td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                    <!--end space height -->

                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="auto" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-radius:5px; font-size:14px; font-family: Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; text-align:left;  color:#5f294f; font-weight: 300; padding-left:
 15px; padding-right: 15px; ">

                                                                                        <a href="http://www.makeitcoats.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f; font-weight: normal;">
                                                                                            <span style=" text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f;
 font-weight: 300;">
                                                                                                Related link 1
                                                                                            </span>
                                                                                        </a>

                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                        <!-- end button -->

                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody></table>

                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                 <!--start space height -->
                                                 <tr>
                                                     <td height="20" class="col-underline"></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                                 <!--end space height -->

                                                </tbody></table>
                                                 <!-- end content left -->

                                                <!-- start space width  -->
                                                <table class="remove" width="40" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;border-collapse:
 collapse;">
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td width="100%" height="3" style="font-size: 0;line-height:
 0;border-collapse: collapse;">

                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                                <!-- end space width  -->

                                                <!-- start content center -->
                                                <table width="160" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="col-3" bgcolor="#ede8e7">

                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td width="100%" valign="top" align="left" class="image-160px">
                                                            <img src="http://passiondev.co.uk/email-newsletter/coats/imageplaceholder.jpg" width="160" alt="image6_280x210" style="max-width:100%;
 display:block !important; " border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0">
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                 <!--start space height -->
                                                 <tr>
                                                     <td height="20"></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                                 <!--end space height -->

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                    <td style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; font-family:
 Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#621a4b; font-weight:bold;
 text-align:left; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                                                                            Crochet
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>

                                                            <!--start space height -->
                                                             <tr>
                                                                 <td height="15"></td>
                                                             </tr>
                                                             <!--end space height -->

                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px; font-family:
 Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#808080; font-weight:300;
 text-align:justify; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; ">

                                                                        Phoomph makes creating decorations and costumes fast and
 easy. Download our free e-book of 13 projects Halloween projects.

                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>

                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top" width="auto">
                                                                        <!-- start button -->
                                                                        <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="auto" align="center" valign="middle" height="40" style="border-radius:5px; font-size:14px; font-family: Arial,Tahoma,
 Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left;  color:#5f294f; font-weight: 300;
 padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; ">

                                                                                        <a href="http://www.makeitcoats.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f; font-weight: bold;">
                                                                                            <span style=" text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f;
 font-weight: bold;">
                                                                                                Read more
                                                                                            </span>
                                                                                        </a>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>

                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="auto" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-radius:5px; font-size:14px; font-family: Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; text-align:left;  color:#5f294f; font-weight: 300; padding-left:
 15px; padding-right: 15px; ">

                                                                                        <a href="http://www.makeitcoats.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f; font-weight: normal;">
                                                                                            <span style=" text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f;
 font-weight: 300;">
                                                                                                Related link 1
                                                                                            </span>
                                                                                        </a>

                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>

                                                                                    <!--start space height -->
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td height="5"></td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                    <!--end space height -->

                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="auto" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-radius:5px; font-size:14px; font-family: Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; text-align:left;  color:#5f294f; font-weight: 300; padding-left:
 15px; padding-right: 15px; ">

                                                                                        <a href="http://www.makeitcoats.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f; font-weight: normal;">
                                                                                            <span style="text-decoration: none;  color: #5f294f;
 font-weight: 300;">
                                                                                                Related link 1
                                                                                            </span>
                                                                                        </a>

                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>

                                                                        </tbody></table>
                                                                        <!-- end button -->

                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody></table>

                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                 <!--start space height -->
                                                 <tr>
                                                     <td height="20" class="col-underline"></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                                 <!--end space height -->

                                                </tbody></table>
                                                 <!-- end content center -->

                                                <!-- start space width  -->
                                                <table class="remove" width="40" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;border-collapse:
 collapse;">
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td width="100%" height="3" style="font-size: 0;line-height:
 0;border-collapse: collapse;">

                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                                <!-- end space width  -->

                                                <!-- start content Right -->
                                                <table width="160" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right" class="col-3" bgcolor="#ede8e7">

                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td width="100%" valign="top" align="left" class="image-160px">
                                                            <img src="http://passiondev.co.uk/email-newsletter/coats/imageplaceholder.jpg" width="160" alt="image6_280x210" style="max-width:100%;
 display:block !important; " border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0">
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                 <!--start space height -->
                                                 <tr>
                                                     <td height="20"></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                                 <!--end space height -->

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                    <td style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; font-family:
 Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#621a4b; font-weight:bold;
 text-align:left; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;">
                                                                            Crochet
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>

                                                            <!--start space height -->
                                                             <tr>
                                                                 <td height="15"></td>
                                                             </tr>
                                                             <!--end space height -->

                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px; font-family:
 Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#808080; font-weight:300;
 text-align:justify; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; ">

                                                                        Phoomph makes creating decorations and costumes fast and
 easy. Download our free e-book of 13 projects Halloween projects.

                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>

                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top" width="auto">
                                                                        <!-- start button -->
                                                                        <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                                            <tbody>
                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="auto" align="center" valign="middle" height="40" style="border-radius:5px; font-size:14px; font-family: Arial,Tahoma,
 Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:left;  color:#5f294f; font-weight: 300;
 padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; ">

                                                                                        <a href="http://www.makeitcoats.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f; font-weight: bold;">
                                                                                            <span style=" text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f;
 font-weight: bold;">
                                                                                                Read more
                                                                                            </span>
                                                                                        </a>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>

                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="auto" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-radius:5px; font-size:14px; font-family: Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; text-align:left;  color:#5f294f; font-weight: 300; padding-left:
 15px; padding-right: 15px; ">

                                                                                        <a href="http://www.makeitcoats.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f; font-weight: normal;">
                                                                                            <span style=" text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f;
 font-weight: 300;">
                                                                                                Related link 1
                                                                                            </span>
                                                                                        </a>

                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>

                                                                                    <!--start space height -->
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td height="5"></td>
                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                    <!--end space height -->

                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td width="auto" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-radius:5px; font-size:14px; font-family: Arial,Tahoma, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; text-align:left;  color:#5f294f; font-weight: 300; padding-left:
 15px; padding-right: 15px; ">

                                                                                        <a href="http://www.makeitcoats.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #5f294f; font-weight: normal;">
                                                                                            <span style="text-decoration: none;  color: #5f294f;
 font-weight: 300;">
                                                                                                Related link 1
                                                                                            </span>
                                                                                        </a>

                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>

                                                                        </tbody></table>
                                                                        <!-- end button -->

                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody></table>

                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                 <!--start space height -->
                                                 <tr>
                                                     <td height="20" class="col-underline"></td>
                                                 </tr>
                                                 <!--end space height -->

                                                </tbody></table>
                                                 <!-- end content right -->

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                         <!-- end image and content -->

                                 </tbody></table>
                                 <!-- end LAYOUT-5 container width 560px -->
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </tbody></table>
                     <!-- end LAYOUT-5 container width 600px -->
                 </td>
             </tr>
```

Comment: Glad that someone changed the name of this post.  Perhaps the OP can suggest a useful name.

Comment: If someone could help me figure this out I would be very regretful.

Comment: The code above  is only a snippet of where the issue is occurring.

Comment: Hmmm I've had a look at your code on codepen.io and it looks ok on there.  Maybe a screenshot would help us out so that we can see the problem :)

Comment: (older than current) IE's didn't respect empty cells. i often ended up with a space like  `<td> </td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the heights from both the empty tables you have between your rows. Generally is a bad tactic defining heights in a newsletter! Also in your empty cells in newsletter always add two space characters.

```
<!-- start space width  -->
                                                <table class="remove" width="200" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="font-size: 0;line-height: 0;border-collapse:
 collapse;">
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td width="100%" style="font-size: 0;line-height:
 0;border-collapse: collapse;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                                <!-- end space width  -->
```

I checked only in outlook, comment me if you have other problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Ws8V/2/

Comment: I took you advice but reduced my spacer height to 1px with two empty spaces. For the last column I simply remove the height attribute now and its looks and work perfect thanks for this tip.

Comment: Also i would like to add that personally i avoid defining width with percentage I use pixels so it is tight. Since most clients do not accept responsive design (like gmail) I think its not worth to risk having a percentage width. In addition I use my css always inlined, there are tools that can inline your css. Good luck mate.